# Generating static files with relative paths with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

How can I change path of files, when generating static with  `yarn run generate`?

For example, I need to get `<img src="images/image.png">` but by default I get `<img src="/image/image.png`  I tried to use config bellow, and I had correct paths for .js files, but code into js-files wasn't running. Thanks for help.

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    })
  }

  if (!ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    config.output.publicPath = '_nuxt/'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load picture from assets directory, files have dynamic paths depending on where they are currently loaded. you can generate a path with the help of a webpage:

```
<img :src="require('~/assets/images/image.png)">
```

On the other hand, in case of static directory - files are copied to the main directory, that's why you're using the path from the main location e.g.

```
<img src="images/image.png">
```